# How to define MODE of Shared_Preferences in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, sharedpreferences, flutter-dependencies, flutter-sharedpreference

In Android, we are defining Shared Preferences Mode like

`getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode)`

> MODE_PRIVATE, MODE_WORLD_READABLE, MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE

How we can define `MODE` in `shared_preferences` flutter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SharedPreferences uses `MODE_PRIVATE` and by now we don't have the option to change this.

The other options are now deprecated and it is not recommended to use then. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE.